# Right side of fieldset jagged in IE

Tags: html, css

I have the following **HTML**:

```html
<div class="body-content">
    <fieldset class="EntryFieldSet">
        <legend id="ScreeningTitle"> Screening:</legend>
        <br/><br/>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

And the following **CSS**:

```css
.body-content {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #F5F5F5 /*whitesmoke*/;
}
.EntryFieldSet {
    width: 250px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

## [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZbNWL/2/)

In **Internet Explorer**, the right side is jagged

[image: IE]

But it appears just fine in **Chrome**

[image: Chrome]

*How can I fix it for all browsers / internet explorer?*

**EDIT** - This issue is happening for me in IE 9 64-bit edition

Comment: What IE version? SOA#1

Comment: Have you tried applying a CSS reset? Each browser may give a default styling to it's elements. It's not only the right side that is jagged, but the left side soo. Seems like rounded corners.

Comment: Have you tested other versions of IE? e.g. 8 or 10? Have you checked to make sure the browser isn't in compatibility mode (either triggered by the doctype, or left over from a previous debugging session)?

Comment: I'm pretty new to web dev so I haven't applied a CSS reset or checked whether or not I'm in compatibility mode.

Comment: You don't need a reset just for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way would be to override the default css. Here is what worked for me

```css
.EntryFieldSet {
   border-radius: 0px;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   border: solid 1px darkgray;
}
```

This way, it displays uniformly and with the same color across all the browsers

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZbNWL/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I have improve the bug just a little bit..

```
 .EntryFieldSet {
        width: 250px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        overflow: hidden;
        border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-top-right-radius: 3px;
        -moz-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px\9;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px\0/;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By applying a zero `border-radius` to the fieldset, I was able to get it to stop trying to apply one by browser default, so now it renders properly

```css
.EntryFieldSet {
    /* other properties */
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
         border-radius: 0px;
}
```

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/ZbNWL/3/)

Example:

[image: demo]